# DataBar in Merged Cells weird behaviour

Tags: c#, excel

I want to pu a DataBar format on a merged cell to display the percentage but the DataBar keep being stuck at 50% no matter the value

[image]

Is there something special to do to make this work?

**UPDATE**
I set the DataBar display with c# and this function :

```
private void createDataBar(Range range)
{
    range.NumberFormat = "# ###,00";
    range.FormatConditions.Delete();
    Databar db = range.FormatConditions.AddDatabar();
    db.BarColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(66,160,227);
}
```

And this function works perfectly but in some other file, when I'm trying to use this function it display the bar at 50% no matter the value even in unmerged cell

*NB:Comma is not for thousands separator*

Comment: @pnuts Well it depends in an excel file it works perfectly, but in another one it doesn't, for merged cells and basic cells

Comment: @pnuts I found the solution see my answer below (it was a little dumb I confess :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

The main problem was not the merged cell or anything but the fact that I called the `AddDatabar` on a range with a single cell (merged or not) thus the databar didn't have any landmark to format the databar (I thought it will use percentage by default but it's not).

So I changed the AddDatBar call to use a multiple cell range if possible or else the way to force the databar to use a percent scale is done with this code

```
Databar db = range.FormatConditions.AddDatabar();
db.MinPoint.Modify(XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber, 0);
db.MaxPoint.Modify(XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber, 100);
```

***NB:*** *I tried the `xlConditionValuePercent` but for some reason it's not working.*